# How does Dependency Inversion works in such case?

Tags: oop, architecture

Good morning,

I have been reading a book from Robert Martin about software architecture and SOLID principles in particular, and I cannot get how does dependency inversion work.

Simple examples, yes, they are clear, like https://www.oodesign.com/dependency-inversion-principle.html

But when we have a plugin system where the parent must know about all plugins and load them, then what to do to avoid dependency of the parent from its plugins?

Example:

```
/*
// In plugins file below
class PluginA { }
class PluginB { }
*/

import { PluginA, PluginB } from '../plugins';

class A {

  private plugins: Plugin[] = [];

  construct() {
    plugins.push(new PluginA(), new PluginB());
  }

}
```

Yes, we defined an interface for all plugins, but we cannot push them without dependency from them, right?

So how to apply the Dependency Inversion principle in this case?
How to use plugins without dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Instead if importing them, construct the plugins elsewhere and inject them into the constuctor for A

```
class A {

  private plugins: Plugin[] = [];

  construct(pluginsToUse) {
    plugins = pluginsToUse;
  }

}
```

Comment: Then we will get the same dependency but in another place, and the Dependency Inversion principle will not be sustained in that place. How to avoid such dependencies? I think it is impossible, we must have a concrete plugin list, but where is the best place to store it? It is the low-level components, I think, but then there will not be the Dependency Inversion principle :)

Comment: Something has to do the work eventually. That is the "injector" (and it is actually called that in Angular) . Don't get hung up on the name of the concept, engineers are very bad at naming things. You might also want to read about the patterns before reading SOLID which essentially rehashes existing ideas.

Comment: @RWRkeSBZ In the case of Angular, I was thinking about how these principles apply to our current development, and it looks like nobody knows about SOLID. Everyone I know develop rigid monolithic applications without flexibility. Now Angular application looks like UI kit + pages by routes + services + UI components, but nobody cares about architecture layers, dependencies, the stability of the architecture components, and so on. Typical Angular page has everything, from model and business logic to view-dependent variables. It is awful, I think.

Comment: Architecture is important, of course, but I wouldn't fuss too much about it in front end development, mostly because from experience most front-ends get redone completely when it is a time for a change.

Comment: @RomanYakimchuk You're misunderstanding dependency inversion.

Comment: No, I am not. This principle tells us to inverse dependencies direction, make them from the bottom (low level and the most modified components) to top components to make them independent from changes of the dependent components. So parent components must have an abstraction.

Comment: @RWRkeSBZ That's the point! I see the same thing, but why do we have to change everything related to an interface when the time to change has come? Why we cannot create architecture that can cover our new requirements? It looks like nobody can write flexible application in frontend, even Angular (see their source code, it has a lot of imports, even not used imports).

Comment: Good luck reinterpreting IoC and refactoring Angular. You might have more luck with the latter, though. All the best.